# Print button is duplicating content

Tags: highcharts

I was creating chart with an additional legend at the bottom with exporting functionality.
Now I've got a strange effect: When opening the printing context menu and choosing one of the download options (PNG/JPG/PDF/SVG) the menu in the bottom of the chart gets duplicated.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},

navigation: {
    buttonOptions: {
        y: 50
    }
},

series: [
      { data: [45.9, 50.2, 45.5, 198.4, 50.2] },
      { data: [68.5, 176.0, 50.1, 123.2, 25.9] },
      { data: [176.4, 50.2, 186.9, 56.6, 58.3] }
    ]
},

function(chart){
    $(chart.series).each(function(i, serie){
        $('<li style="color: ' + serie.color + '">' + serie.name + '</li>').click(function(){
            serie.visible ? serie.hide() : serie.show();
        }).appendTo('#legend')
    })
});
```

Any ideas to avoid this?

You can try here: http://jsfiddle.net/pepesale/NTjsJ/4/

Answer (score 0):

Looks weird. However you can check if the UL is empty before appending.

```
function(chart){
    //Check the list is Empty before appending...
    if($('#legend').is(":empty")) { 
      $(chart.series).each(function(i, serie){
        $('<li style="color: '+serie.color+'">'+serie.name+' ('+ serie.symbol + ')</li>').click(function(){
            serie.visible ? serie.hide() : serie.show();
        }).appendTo('#legend');
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Now we avoid duplication of content. That's just better than before.

Comment: Umfortunately after having exported the chart the bottom menu doesn't work any more...